# How to combine two C# Expressions using API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-expressions

Say I have two classes like the following:

```cs
public class A
{
  public B B { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
  public string SomeValue { get; set; } 
}
```

And the following expressions:

```cs
using System.Linq.Expressions;
// Actual expression much more complicated
Expression<Func<B, string>> mainExpression = b => b.SomeValue; 
Expression<Func<A, B>> aToB = a => a.B;
```

How would I combine them? Obviously I could write

```cs
Expression<Func<A, string>> newExpression = a => a.B.SomeValue;
```

But the real "`mainExpression`" is much more complicated and I'd like to avoid code duplication.

I'm using EntityFramework, these are classes representing database tables, which is why I need a `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace parameter of `mainExpression` with a body of `aToB` (for example using [`ReplacingExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.replacingexpressionvisitor?view=efcore-5.0) available since EF Core 3.0 or write [your own one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68179457/2501279) if you are using earlier version) and build a new expression tree:

```cs
Expression<Func<B, string>> mainExpression = b => b.SomeValue; 
Expression<Func<A, B>> aToB = a => a.B;
var visit = new ReplacingExpressionVisitor(new[] {mainExpression.Parameters[0]}, new[] {aToB.Body})
    .Visit(mainExpression.Body);
var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<A, string>>(visit, aToB.Parameters);
```

Comment: Does this work with EF still do you know?

Comment: @Adam yes, it should (depends on actual expressions though). Have you tried it?

Comment: I'll have to write my own I think. I'm using EF6 but this definitely helps.

Comment: @GuruStron: Can I ask how you'd use this class to replace a parameter with a newly defined `ParameterExpression`? I was using a custom `ExpressionVisitor` class. But I'm not sure what the arguments should be to the `ReplacingExpressionVisitor` constructor.

Comment: @GuruStron: Thanks, the first argument is the one giving me trouble. Looks like in your case it's just the first parameter to your expression. Unfortunately, I have my code working with a plain `Expression`, which has no `Parameters` property. And I'm having trouble working through the errors when I change the expression to a lambda.

Comment: @JonathanWood can you please show the code?

Comment: @GuruStron: I would appreciate it. I've created a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68644895/replace-custom-expressionvisitor-with-replacingexpressionvisitor).