# Replace custom ExpressionVisitor with ReplacingExpressionVisitor

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, .net-5

I have the code below working.

But instead of using the custom `ParameterReplacer` class like I am, I would prefer if I could eliminate this class and use `ReplacingExpressionVisitor` instead. But I can't seem to find the right syntax where I can get the existing parameter so that I can replace it with `parameter`.

#### GetDateExpression

```
protected readonly Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> GetDateExpression;
```

#### ParameterReplacer

```
internal class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression Parameter;

    internal ParameterReplacer(ParameterExpression parameter)
    {
        Parameter = parameter;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return base.VisitParameter(Parameter);
    }
}
```

#### Main Code

```
Expression expression;
Expression startExpression, endExpression;

// Build sub expressions
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
startExpression = startDate.HasValue ?
    Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(GetNullableDateExpression.Body, Expression.Constant(startDate, typeof(DateTime?))) :
    null;
endExpression = endDate.HasValue ?
    Expression.LessThanOrEqual(GetNullableDateExpression.Body, Expression.Constant(endDate, typeof(DateTime?))) :
    null;

// Build main expression
if (startExpression != null && endExpression != null)
    expression = Expression.AndAlso(startExpression, endExpression);
else if (startExpression != null)
    expression = startExpression;
else
    expression = endExpression;

// TODO: Change to use ReplacingExpressionVisitor instead

// Use our real parameter
expression = new ParameterReplacer(parameter)
    .Visit(expression);

// Modify query
return query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expression, parameter));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually better to replace parameter before combining:

```cs
Expression expression;
Expression startExpression, endExpression;

// Build sub expressions
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

var nullableExpressionBody = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(GetNullableDateExpression.Body, GetNullableDateExpression.Parameters[0], parameter);

startExpression = startDate.HasValue ?
    Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(nullableExpressionBody, Expression.Constant(startDate, typeof(DateTime?))) :
    null;
endExpression = endDate.HasValue ?
    Expression.LessThanOrEqual(nullableExpressionBody, Expression.Constant(endDate, typeof(DateTime?))) :
    null;

// Build main expression
if (startExpression != null && endExpression != null)
    expression = Expression.AndAlso(startExpression, endExpression);
else if (startExpression != null)
    expression = startExpression;
else
    expression = endExpression;

// Modify query
return query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expression, parameter));
```

Also if you reuse parameter from `GetNullableDateExpression` lambda, replacing is not needed.

```cs
// Build sub expressions
var parameter = GetNullableDateExpression.Parameters[0];

startExpression = startDate.HasValue ?
    Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(GetNullableDateExpression.Body, Expression.Constant(startDate, typeof(DateTime?))) :
    null;
endExpression = endDate.HasValue ?
    Expression.LessThanOrEqual(GetNullableDateExpression.Body, Expression.Constant(endDate, typeof(DateTime?))) :
    null;
```